# Recurring Calender Item Property

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am trying to read Outlook calendar appointments. I do have some serial appointments which have only one entry in my Calendar object with the property `IsRecurring = 1` and `RecurrenceState = 1`. But I haven't found a property which says how often the appointment is recurring.

What is the best way to get this information?

The goal is by the way to display outlook appointments within a given time-span. So far I can read my serial appointments only at the date where the first entry occurs.

Comment: How are you talking to outlook ? Interop or EWS ?

Comment: Via Interop. I think i have found a solution. Is GetRecurrencePattern.Occurrences the right choice?